# PHP - Security concern. Am I safe from SQL injection/XSS

Tags: php, mysql, xss, sql-injection

This question is everywhere, and I looked at many answers. A lot suggest using mysql_real_escape_string But that isn't an option, since it's depreciated now.
Being a rookie at PHP/SQL and especially when it comes to security, I can only hope some of you may be able to help out here. I know for a fact that some of these procedures I already use contribute to security (As an example: I didn't use :pname before when defining query_params. Which caused SQL to interpret submissions like 'values'; drop table dbname; as actual commands. One thing that did save me from the command not being executed is the conversion of spaces to underscores)

PHP code in 'search_submit.php'

```
<?php
$pname=str_replace(' ','_',strtolower($_GET['pname']));
require 'connection.php';
  if(isset($_GET['pname'])){

  if(preg_match("/\w/i", $_GET['pname'])){
   $query="SELECT SCHEMA_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA WHERE   SCHEMA_NAME = :pname;";
           $query_params = array( 
             ':pname' => str_replace(' ','_',strtolower($_GET['pname']))
        );
   $prep=$conn->prepare($query);
   $result=$prep->execute($query_params) or die("failed!");
   $row = $prep->fetch(); 
        if($row) 
        { 
            die("Exists"); 
        }
        else{
            echo("doesn't");
        }
  }
  }
  else{
  echo  "<p>Error</p>";
  }
?>
```

HTML code in 'index.html':

```
<form  method="get" action="search_submit.php"  id="searchform">
  <input  type="text" name="pname">
  <input  type="submit" name="input" value="Search">
```

As of right now everything appears to be working perfectly, and any sneaky submissions are simply interpreted as text. But I am a very paranoid person.

Any recommendations/changes are greatly appreciated.

Comment: the code reviewing questions you can ask on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ review blog, here you question when, you have an error.

Comment: Will do. Wasn't aware that existed and saw many people asking similar questions here. Sorry.

Comment: One easy way to find out would be to try an attack yourself?